# Добавление номера в блока

Tags: jquery

Как создать функцию, при которой при нажатие на кнопку  создавался блок и добавлялся к нему номер.

Например есть классический блок #1
При нажатие на кнопку создавался новый блок только к нему добавлялась следующая цифра и так каждый раз при клике на кнопку. Помогите реализовать и понять данную функцию.

Comment: "При нажатие" - ? -1

Answer (score 2):

Там много чего можно добавить в процессе создания, но конкретно нумерацию можно делать на CSS-counter)

```js
let add = document.getElementById('add');

add.addEventListener('click', function(){
  createIn(document.body, 'div', 'bubu');
});

function createIn(parent, tag, className){
  let node = document.createElement(tag);
  node.className = className;
  parent.appendChild(node);

  return node;
}
```

```css
.bubu {
  counter-increment: bubu;
}

.bubu::before {
  content: "#" counter(bubu);
}
```

```html
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

То же самое на jQuery:

```js
$('#add').on('click', function(){
  createIn('body', 'div', 'bubu');
});

function createIn(parent, tag, className){
  var $node = $('<' + tag + '>').prop('class', className);
  $(parent).append($node);
  
  return $node;
}
```

```css
.bubu {
  counter-increment: bubu;
}

.bubu::before {
  content: "#" counter(bubu);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="add">Add</button>
```

И, нумерация без CSS, на jQ:

```js
var i = 1;
$('#add').on('click', function(){
  $('body').append( '<div>#' + (i++) + '</div>' );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(e){
  let elem = document.createElement('div'),
      container = document.querySelector('.container');
  elem.id = '#'+container.childNodes.length;
  elem.innerHTML = '#'+container.childNodes.length;
  container.append(elem);
};
```

```html
<button>Create Element</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Всё хорошо, если конечно этот номер хранить не надо.

Comment: @spoon100500 а зачем его хранить если его в любое время можно взять?

Comment: после перезагрузки страницы нумерация снова будет с 0 идти.